# Swift: Table view section titles

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

Can any one explain the difference between these two section titles and that how can I achieve the default iOS section titles as in the setting image shown below. Thanks for the help.
Im using the following function to set title and I expect this to be a default feature.

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "This is me title"
    }
```

This is the title I get on my sections.
[image: Here you can see title is bold black and no paddings.]

[image: While this is how it should look like.]

Comment: May be you need to change height for header and color to achieve UI like image. Find delegate methods related to header customization

Comment: The default one from settings seems to be using Grouped tableView

Comment: Grouped Table Views? Ok Im checking into it now, hopefully that answers my problem. Will update in a while.

Comment: @Tj3n yeah grouped one it is! you rock. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same header as Settings can be achieved by using tableView's `Grouped` style